# Scala spark: Create List of Dataset from a Dataset map operation

Tags: scala, apache-spark, generics

Suppose I want to create 2 types of metric : metricA or metricB after transforming another dataset. If a certain condition is met, it'll generate both metricA and B, if condition is not met, generate only metric A. The idea is to write the 2 metrics to 2 different paths (pathA, pathB).

The approach I took was to create a Dataset of GeneralMetric and then based on whats inside, write to different paths, but obviously it didn't work as pattern matching inside Dataset wouldn't work

```
val s: SparkSession = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("Metric")
    .getOrCreate()
import s.implicits._

case class original (id : Int, units: List[Double])

case class MetricA (a: Int, b: Int, filtered_unit: List[Double])
case class MetricB (a: Int, filtered_unit: List[Double])
case class GeneralMetric(metricA: MetricA, metricB: Option[MetricB])

def createA: MetricA = {
    MetricA(1, 1, List(1.0, 2.0)
}

def createB: MetricB = {
    MetricB(1, List(10.0, 20.0)
}
def create (isBoth: Boolean): GeneralMetric = {
    if(isBoth) {
       val a: MetricA = createA()
       val b: MetricB = createB()
       GeneralMetric(a, Some(b))
    }
    else {
       val a: MetricA = createA()
       GeneralMetric(a, None)
    }
}

val originalDF: DataFrame

val result : Dataset[GeneralMetric] =
                 originalDF.as[original]
                 .map { r =>
                      if(r.id == 21) create(true)
                      else create(false)
                 }

val pathA: String = "s3://pathA"
val pathB: String = "s3://pathB"

//below code obviously wouldn't work
result.map(x => {
    case (metricA, Some(metricB)) => {
      metricA.write.parquet(pathA)
      metricB.write.parquet(pathB)
    }
    case (metricA, None) => metricA.write.parquet(pathA)

  })
```

The next approach I was thinking of, was putting the results in a List[GeneralMetric], where GeneralMetric is a **sealed trail**, extended by both MetricA and MetricB, but how can I make a dataset transformation return a list of GeneralMetric.

Any ideas would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why wouldn't

```
result.map({
    case (metricA, Some(metricB)) =>
      metricA.write.parquet(pathA)
      metricB.write.parquet(pathB)
    case (metricA, None) => metricA.write.parquet(pathA)

  })
```

work in your case? Is this just a syntax problem?

---

Also: it seems that you send metrics independently (or at least in this example). You could model it as:

```
sealed trait Metric {
  def write
}
case class MetricA (a: Int, b: Int, filtered_unit: List[Double]) extends Metric {
  override def write: Unit = ???
}
case class MetricB (a: Int, filtered_unit: List[Double]) extends Metric {
  override def write: Unit = ???
}
```

and call

```
implicit val enc: Encoder[Metric] = Encoders.kryo[Metric]
val result: Dataset[Metric] =
    originalDF.as[original]
      .flatMap { r =>
        if (r.id == 21) createA :: createB :: Nil
        else createA :: Nil
      }
result.foreach(metric.write.parquet())
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the alternative, I prefer it your  way as adding more metrics is much easier, than updating the general metric everytime. 
However , I still face the old enemy of writing out diff. metrics to diff paths .
I mean I am left with Dataset[Metric] and the above foreach doesn't work. The write function doesnt have any parquet DataFrameWriter utility. Any idea how do I write to diff path: pathA, pathB

Also I thought foreach on a Dataset, will try to access each row of the dataset

Comment: I've posted a separate question reg the writing to different paths. I've accepted your answer as it solves my original question.

Can you please check it out:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61054782/write-parquet-files-to-different-paths-in-s3-based-on-pattern-matching-of-a-trai